# how to clear textbox text in C++/XAML

Tags: c++, xaml

im new to C++/XAML, using VS2012, working on my first Windows 8 app.

I have created a textbox1 that take a number, another textbox2 that display the results, another button that once it is clicked, it does the calculation. everything works, my question is when user want to do the calculation again, he will need to click on textbox1, press the backspace to erased the last entered number, how can i make it when textbox1 is clicked and tapped, it will auto clear the previously entered text? or how do i use/make a "CLEAR" button to handle the text clearing for textbox1 and textbox2? Thank You!

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointerpressed.aspx). My experience using Windows 8 is limited by now, but it should help.

Comment: thanks, too bad there is no C++ codes with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With button:

```
<Button Content="Clear" Name="button1" Click="button1_Click" />
```

Code behind:

```
void YourClass::button1_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ args)
{
    textBox1->Text = "";
    textBox2->Text = "";
}
```

If you want to use some logic when you tap or something else you should take a look at Tapped event. I'd do it another way: Whenever it got focus(GotFocus event) then select all the text in text box(textBox1->SelectAll(); in GotEvent handler).

Comment: Just a quick hint: in XAML editor when you type, for example, `<TextBlock  GotFocus="" />`, you can put mouse between "" and hit ctrl+spacebar, after that choose "New handler" in the IntelliSense popup and it will generate event handler for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

SetWindowText is a function to set the contents of a Edit Control

m_myEditCtrl.SetWindowText(_T("")); // if using MFC

SetWindowText(hWndMyEditCtrl,_T("")); // When using plain Win32 API

myEditCtrl.Text = ""; // When using C++CLI

You can use it from the "On Click" handler also if needed!

Answer (score 0):

I think that could be useful, if you just add in the end of the program that apply to your textboxes a new button with:

```
textBox2->Text = String::Empty;
textBox1->Text = String::Empty;
```

OR

…you could add these code lines before start the procedure of the program, just in the beginning of the program. Each time it would start over with blank.

Cheers.